# Iphone bluetooth connected to a non-MFI device

Tags: iphone, connection, device, mfi

Could I connect a non-registered-MFI device to interact with my iPhone via Bluetooth? I would like to connect this device using some connection such as Bluetooth, RS232 or any other kind of connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connecting to non-registered-MFI device you have to jail-break your iPhone and then you can connect it by writing code in C.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any option of doing it without jail breaking the iPhone?

Comment: No, there is no option to connect to non-MFi approved devices.